# Categorize number of occurrences

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the program to tell me, dependent on the user's entries, how many individuals fall into the categories "Underweight", "Normal Weight", and "Overweight". Every time I run it, I keep getting the response 0. Can someone tell me what it is I am doing wrong?

---

```
def under(BMIs):
    return BMIs < 25
def normal(BMIs):
    return BMIs >= 25 and BMIs < 35
def over(BMIs):
    return BMIs > 35
print ("This program will help calculate the body mass index of 6 people")
individuals = list()
for i in range(6):
    user = str(input("Please enter the name of one of the individuals: "))
    individuals.append(user)
    
BMIs = list()
for user in individuals:
    print("Calculating for", user)
    height = int(input(user + ", in inches, how tall are you? "))
    weight = int(input(user + ", in pounds, how much do you weight? "))
    BMIs.append(weight * 703/height**2)
for i, bmi in enumerate(BMIs):
    if under(bmi):
        print (individuals[i], "is underweight")
    elif normal(bmi):
        print (individuals[i], "is normal weight")
    elif over(bmi):
        print (individuals[i], "is overweight")
count1 = BMIs.count(under)
count2 = BMIs.count(normal)
count3 = BMIs.count(over)
print ("The number of under weight individuals is: ", count1)
print ("The number of normal weight individuals is: ", count2)
print ("The number of over weight individuals is: ", count3)
```

---

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Did you notice that someone with a BMI of exactly 35 will not fall into either normal nor over cagetory?  Also, your BMI scales are way off from conventional charts that put 25 at the lower threshold of overweight, and under as being below 18

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
count1 = BMIs.count(under)
```

is counting how many times *the function* `under` *itself* is present in the `BMIs` list - not how many elements of the `BMIs` list evaluate to `True` once they go into that function.

Here's an idea to change that: we add a 1 to another list whenever the function `under` evaluates to `True` for a given bmi, then simply ask for the list's length:

```
individuals_under = []
for bmi in BMIs:
    if under(bmi):
        people_under.append(1)
count1 = len(individuals_under)
```

Another solution is to use a list comprehension and count how many bmis return `True` for each function - which is simpler, but you may not be familiar with the syntax yet:

```
count1 = [under(bmi) for bmi in BMIs].count(True)
```

Hopefully this is clear enough so that you understand why it happens to `count2` and `count3` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Like [@jfaccioni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11161432/jfaccioni) said

The line

```
count1 = BMIs.count(under)
```

is counting how many times the function `under` itself is present in the BMIs list - not how many elements of the BMIs list evaluate to `True` once they go into that function.

However, I have a slightly different approach to [@jfaccioni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11161432/jfaccioni)

```
    def under(BMIs):
    return BMIs < 25
def normal(BMIs):
    return BMIs >= 25 and BMIs < 35
def over(BMIs):
    return BMIs > 35

print ("This program will help calculate the body mass index of 6 people")
individuals = []
for i in range(1):
    user = str(input("Please enter the name of one of the individuals: "))
    individuals.append(user)
    
BMIs = []
for user in individuals:
    print("Calculating for", user)
    height = int(input(user + ", in inches, how tall are you? "))
    weight = int(input(user + ", in pounds, how much do you weight? "))
    BMIs.append(weight * 703/height**2)

Count = []
for i, bmi in enumerate(BMIs):
    if under(bmi):
        print (individuals[i], "is underweight")
        Count.append("under")
    elif normal(bmi):
        print (individuals[i], "is normal weight")
        Count.append("normal")
    elif over(bmi):
        print (individuals[i], "is overweight")
        Count.append("over")

count1 = Count.count("under")
count2 = Count.count("normal")
count3 = Count.count("over")
print ("The number of under weight individuals is: ", count1)
print ("The number of normal weight individuals is: ", count2)
print ("The number of over weight individuals is: ", count3)
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure if I'm doing something wrong but I keep getting 0 as a result still.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo. Just edited my code, try it now.